# define, initialize and use types in js-ctypes

Tags: c++, winapi, smartcard, jsctypes, winscard

SCardTransmit function is defined in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I want to declare and use this function, I have problems with the definition of some arguments in js-ctypes (especially in type casting):

1. LPCSCARD_IO_REQUEST: A pointer to the protocol header structure
2. LPCBYTE: A pointer to the actual data to be written to the card
3. LPBYTE: Pointer to a 32-byte buffer that receives the ATR string from the currently inserted card, if available. (this arg is in the status function)

How Can define, initialize and use them?

**Here my code:**

```
//-----------------define types----------------------    
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');
var TYPES = {
ABI: is64bit ? ctypes.default_abi : ctypes.winapi_abi,
DWORD: ctypes.uint32_t,
LONG: ctypes.long,
BYTE: ctypes.unsigned_char //ctypes.uint8_t
};
TYPES.LPDWORD = TYPES.DWORD.ptr;
TYPES.SCARDCONTEXT = TYPES.ULONG_PTR;
TYPES.SCARDHANDLE = TYPES.ULONG_PTR;
TYPES.LPBYTE = TYPES.BYTE.ptr;
var CONST = { 
SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0: 0x00000000,
SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1: 0x00000001
}

const SCARD_IO_REQUEST = new ctypes.StructType("myStruct" ,
                   [{"dwProtocol": TYPES.DWORD},
                    {"cbPciLength": TYPES.DWORD}]);

//------------------declaration-------------------------
var SCardTransmit = cardLib.declare('SCardTransmit', TYPES.ABI, TYPES.LONG, TYPES.SCARDHANDLE, SCARD_IO_REQUEST.ptr, TYPES.LPBYTE, TYPES.DWORD, SCARD_IO_REQUEST.ptr, TYPES.LPBYTE, TYPES.LPDWORD);
//------------------initializing---------------------
var _SCARD_IO_REQUEST = new SCARD_IO_REQUEST;
    _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.dwProtocol = CONST.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0|CONST.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1;
    _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.cbPciLength = _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.dwProtocol.toString().length;
var command = ctypes.char.array(42)("00a4040010a0000000183003010000000000000000");
var commandLength = command.toString().length;
var response = TYPES.LPBYTE;
var responseLength = TYPES.LPDWORD;      
//----------------using-------------------------
var rez_SCT = SCardTransmit(cardHandle, _SCARD_IO_REQUEST, command, commandLength, null, response, responseLength.address());
if(rez_SCT.toString() != CONST.SCARD_S_SUCCESS.toString())
    {
      console.error('cannot begin transaction, error code was: ' + rez_SCT + ' in other terms it is: 0x' + rez_SCT.toString(16) + ' you can look up this error value here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#smart_card_return_values');
      throw new Error('failed to begin transactio!');
     }
```

Comment: What exactly don't you know/understand? The MSDN page pretty much explains how to use it.

Comment: for example I defined LPCSCARD_IO_REQUEST as follows, is it true?

const SCARD_IO_REQUEST = new ctypes.StructType("myStruct", [{"dwProtocol": TYPES.DWORD},
{"cbPciLength": TYPES.DWORD}]);

Comment: You have a lot of questoins, and there is missing stuff in the code above. Can you maintain your full code on github somewhere so I can help guide you. Otherwise I have to start from scratch and rebuild everytime I try to help you. I requested this in your other topic as well.

Comment: We sorted this out on IRC, the solution is an ongong collaboration. This topic can be deleted/closed.

Comment: Always I have problem with type conversion in jsctypes. even now I have problem with export function (in getAtribute and setAttribute types should be precise defined). I think it is a very good idea that you write a paper sheet for this conversion, because the referencs are sparse and vague.